# when ı connect Heroku Postgres to Heroku ı get an internal server error

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, flask, heroku, sqlalchemy

I have a flask app ı want to deploy on Heroku it is working without Heroku Postgres but when ı add Heroku Postgres ı get the below error

```
--- no python application found, check your startup logs for errors ---
2021-07-26T07:55:39.367930+00:00 app[web.1]: {address space usage: 57741312 bytes/55MB} {rss usage: 12115968 bytes/11MB} [pid: 7|app: -1|req: -1/4] 10.32.150.15 () {58 vars in 1134 bytes} [Mon Jul 26 07:55:39 2021] GET /favicon.ico => generated 21 bytes in 0 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 83 bytes (0 switches on core 0)
2021-07-26T07:55:39.370298+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=flask-first-example.herokuapp.com request_id=c4a978b4-bff6-46cb-bcdf-a626d12ea301 fwd="85.98.12.22" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=5ms status=500 bytes=104 protocol=https
```

I could not fix the problem although ı try lots of things

https://github.com/yunusaltuntas/flask-example.git

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Procfile and a requirements.txt file in the directory ? If not, create a file name "Procfile" and insert the following `web: gunicorn app:app`.In my case, my flask app file is called app.py that't why I used app:app. The requirements.txt file should have all the modules your app needs, you can do this with `pip3 freeze > requirements.txt`, use the pip version your app uses. This might help.